# This for loop is unwilling to pass, no method error

Tags: ruby, for-loop

If I have:

```
@pet_shop = {
  pets: [
    {
      name: "Sir Percy",
      pet_type: :cat,
      breed: "British Shorthair",
      price: 500
    },
    {
      name: "King Bagdemagus",
      pet_type: :cat,
      breed: "British Shorthair",
      price: 500
    }
  ]
}
```

I need a function that returns the pet if I give it the "name", so I have:

```
def find_pet_by_name(pet_shop, name)
  for pet in pet_shop[:pets]
    if pet[:name] == name
      return pet
    else return nil
    end
  end
end
```

But this is not passing the test. I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

This is such a simple function, I do not know why it doesn't pass.

Comment: Can you specifiy which line this error relates to please?
Can you also provide the code where you call `find_pet_by_name`?

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is that you do not complete the loop. You return either `pet` or `nil` for the first value of `pet`, namely, the `"Sir Percy"` hash. Your code should be as follows.

```
def find_pet_by_name(pet_shop, name)
  for pet in pet_shop[:pets]
    return pet if pet[:name] == name
  end
  nil
end

find_pet_by_name @pet_shop, "King Bagdemagus"
  #=> {:name=>"King Bagdemagus", :pet_type=>:cat, :breed=>"British Shorthair",
  #    :price=>500}
```

I would suggest you instead use the method [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find).

```
name = "King Bagdemagus"
@pet_shop[:pets].find { |h| h[:name] == name }
   #=> {:name=>"King Bagdemagus", :pet_type=>:cat, :breed=>"British Shorthair",
   #    :price=>500} 

name = "Queen Bagdemagus"
@pet_shop[:pets].find { |h| h[:name] == name }
   #=> nil
```

Incidentally, Rubiests rarely use `for` loops. (I've *never* used one). It's better to use an enumerator, such as `each`, `find`, `select`, `reduce`, in part because the value of the iteration variable (here `pet`) is not visible outside an enumerator's block.